# How to get the email address of an owner of an npm package?

Tags: node.js, npm

You used to be able to get the email address of an owner of an npm package via:
GET https://registry.npmjs.org/-/user/org.couchdb.user:username

However, it is now responding with:
401 {"ok":false}

Any idea how to get it now?

Comment: I sometimes use https://api.npms.io/v2/package/couchdb

Answer (score 2):

use [`npm view`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view.html)

> This command shows data about a package and prints it

```sh
$ npm view couchdb _npmUser
nathan <nrstott@gmail.com>
```

or

```sh
$ npm view couchdb maintainers.email
nrstott@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `npm owner ls` if you want to list users who have access to modify a package and push new versions. It defaults to the package in the current directory (if any), and it also accepts an argument to list owners of the specified package, for example:

```
$ npm owner ls lodash
mathias <mathias@qiwi.be>
jdalton <john.david.dalton@gmail.com>
bnjmnt4n <benjamin@dev.ofcr.se>
```

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/owner.html